# Is there any way to get long-lived code/access tokens for Instagram Basic Display Api?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

Access token is being expired after one hour as it is also mentioned in API documentation. It is not convenient for the users to authorize again after every hour.

Please let me know if there is any other way to get long-lived tokens or refresh the token.

Documentation reference is below:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview

Thank you

Comment: There is non. I don't know why. It's crazy for me. You are even not allowed to use it for authentification and are forced to use Facebook Login.

Comment: There is some news? same problem for me

Comment: @Shadrix 2 days ago long-lived tokens with refresh capabilities came out for the Instagram Basic API.

Comment: @roiekoper ^^^^

Comment: @David nice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can now get long-lived Instagram User Access Tokens which are valid for 60 days and can be refreshed. Please note that long-lived access tokens are currently in Beta.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens